# Calculate the difference

Tags: python, numpy, difference, calculation

I have data file: [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJbXp.png)
I need to make X differences (1st column), but only when the 3rd column is 1.

```
import numpy as np

x,jump= np.loadtxt("data.svc",delimiter=' ',skiprows=1, usecols=(0,3),unpack=True)

resultX = list()

i=0
while (i<len(jump)):
    if jump[i] == 1:
        while(jump[i] == 1):
            i+=1
            temp = i
            resultX.append((abs(x[temp]-x[temp-1])))
    i+=1

print(resultX)
```

My results are: `5,7,4,12,8,6,9,5,4,11` that's wrong

I need: `5,7,4,8,6,5,4`
[correct results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK6s2.png)

Comment: share the .svc file.

Comment: Do you really not want to get the subsequent X values with `j == 1` like 116 and 147, that happen to be interrupted by one or more `j == 0` rows?

Comment: file: [link](https://ufile.io/ab3dy).

Comment: I not want ,,147-116,,.   Yes, j==0 to can be one or more rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
>>> diff = np.diff(x)
>>> diff
array([ 5,  7,  4, 12,  4, 15,  8,  6,  9,  5,  5,  4,  5,  4, 11])
>>> 
>>> flag = np.diff(jump) + jump[1:]
>>> flag
array([ 1,  1,  1, -1,  0,  2,  1,  1, -1,  0,  0,  2,  1,  1, -1])
>>> 
>>> diff[flag == 1]
array([5, 7, 4, 8, 6, 5, 4])
```

Comment: `flag = np.diff(a[:, 3]) + a[1:, 3]` IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't spot that you were only unpacking the two columns, I thought you had the whole array. I edited my answer: just change the column `3` to `1`.

Comment: The same problem: `np.diff(a[:, 1]) + a[1:, 1]` IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: OK, apologies, I see now you're reading into two different arrays. I changed the code again.

Comment: Error is solved, but I do not understand how to enter:  `diff [flag == 1]`  to the code?????

Comment: You think like this: `finalList = list()
for i in range(len(flag)):
    if flag[i] == 1:
        finalList.append(d[i]) `

Comment: `resultX = diff[flag == 1]` should do it — put all three lines immediately after the  `np.loadtxt()` line.

Comment: No, it is not working: NameError: name 'diff' is not defined. Never mind. I I did it over the cycle FOR. Thaanks.

Comment: Could you explain to me: `np.diff(jump) + jump[1:]` ?

Comment: The `flag` step is just to try to make an array that tell us which values to ignore. It's a bit hacky; there are probably lots of ways to do it, it was the first thing that occurred to me.